# How to continuously restart countdown when it elapse

Tags: javascript, countdown, countdowntimer

I'm using a countdown timer script that I've come across online and modified slightly to suit my website. This works perfectly for counting down to a set date/time but I need the timer to pause for about 1 hour and continue counting for 7 days. For example, when it reaches its end which is Wednesday 00:00:00, it should wait for an hour and then starts counting again till next Wednesday and so on and so fort. 
-please i need help!
-here is the code i use

```
function teus(){
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Apr 3, 2018 18:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

// Get todays date and time
var now = new Date().getTime();

// Find the distance between now an the count down date
var distance = countDownDate - now;

// Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

// Output the result in an element with id="demo"
document.getElementById("teu").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
+ minutes + "m " + seconds + "s "  +  "";

// If the count down is over, write some text
if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("teu").innerHTML = "Service Time";

}
}, 1000);
}
teus()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any error messages?

Comment: Thanks very mush for the fast reply. Please i am just mixed up. do not even know how to go about it. Please, i am trying to build the website for our church and the code is meant to count how long it is to the next service day.

Comment: Please someone should help  me out please. i am begging.